# can't able to login whalewisdom website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

> I'm trying to login whalewisdom website for last two week but I'm not able to log in, I was tried many libraries like scrapy, selenium, beautifulsoup, etc...

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 
with Session() as s:
    login_url = s.get("https://whalewisdom.com/login")
    bs_content = bs(login_url.content, "lxml")
    authenticity_token = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"authenticity_token"})["value"]
    login_data = {
        "authenticity_token": authenticity_token,
        "login": "info@example.com",
        "password": "***********",
        "commit": "Log+In",
    }
    s.post("https://whalewisdom.com/session", data=login_data)
    html_data = bs(s.get("https://whalewisdom.com/dashboard").content, "html.parser")
    print(html_data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWbMF.png)

> Here the outputenter image description here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>[enter image description here][1]
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>WhaleWisdom Dashboard</title>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="WhaleWisdom tracks 13F, Schedule 13D, and 13G EDGAR filings by hedge funds. Hedge Fund Whale Backtesting and search tools" name="description"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/favicon-96x96.png" rel="icon" sizes="96x96" type="image/png"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
<meta content="r4hQnHlN2H-GtcIb06YHl49VSipApmfQQWIOvZzfnAU" name="google-site-verification">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/packs/css/whalewisdom-24fbc382.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="XMAu/LK+dKi/zt/XSTvxIJ8jKl2x8Rx47/ZnAiN6MQCcZmSSlUrOLMeURRr54eCfEWHY8oyS8c6GYxLoIMomNQ==" name="csrf-token">
</meta></meta></link></meta></head>
<body>
<noscript>
<strong>We're sorry but the WhaleWisdom Dashboard doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/packs/js/whalewisdom-4b32da19479fdebf5332.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-11651599-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async="" charset="utf-8" src="//ads.investingchannel.com/adtags/WhaleWisdom/quotepages/970x91.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see that in the HTML output, at line 23, there is an error type message stating that the WhaleWisdom dashboard doesn't work properly without JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>[enter image description here][1]
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>WhaleWisdom Dashboard</title>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="WhaleWisdom tracks 13F, Schedule 13D, and 13G EDGAR filings by hedge funds. Hedge Fund Whale Backtesting and search tools" name="description"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/favicon-96x96.png" rel="icon" sizes="96x96" type="image/png"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/images/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
<meta content="r4hQnHlN2H-GtcIb06YHl49VSipApmfQQWIOvZzfnAU" name="google-site-verification">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/packs/css/whalewisdom-24fbc382.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="XMAu/LK+dKi/zt/XSTvxIJ8jKl2x8Rx47/ZnAiN6MQCcZmSSlUrOLMeURRr54eCfEWHY8oyS8c6GYxLoIMomNQ==" name="csrf-token">
</meta></meta></link></meta></head>
<body>
----
<noscript>
<strong>We're sorry but the WhaleWisdom Dashboard doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>**
</noscript>
----
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://d27mjrcvcy56qq.cloudfront.net/packs/js/whalewisdom-4b32da19479fdebf5332.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-11651599-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async="" charset="utf-8" src="//ads.investingchannel.com/adtags/WhaleWisdom/quotepages/970x91.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think because of this it is not working. I also can't test it right now because I don't use WhaleWisdom.